# Add products with different sizes and price to Cart | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, shopping-cart

I use session's to create a shopping cart. I have a product model and a model for Product-sizes, which I define the size-title(XL , etc) and price of  product in it . So that I can have products with different sizes  as well as different prices. But my logic has some problems

if I add product_1 with size A  , it's ok ...

if I add product_1 with size B , it's ok ...

but when I'm trying to add same product with different sizes at same time the cart only shows the price of first size

```
#shop/models.py

class ProductSizes(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  price = models.IntegerField()
  picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" )


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(ProductSizes , blank=True , related_name="sizes" )
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

---

```
#cart/cart.py

from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product

class Cart:
    def __init__(self,request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
            
        self.cart = cart
        
    # add to cart
    def add(self,product,size_,quantity=1,override_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        print(product.size.name)
        if product_id not in self.cart  :
            if size_ != None:
                if  size_.off_price:
                    self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity':0,'price':size_.off_price}
                elif size_.price:
                    self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity':0,'price':size_.price}

            else:
                if product.off_price:
                    self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity':0,'price':product.off_price}
                else:
                    self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity':0,'price':product.price}

        if override_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
   

        self.save()
    
    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True
    
    #remove from cart
    def remove(self,product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()
    
    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
        
        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item
    
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(item['price'] * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
    
    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

ــــــــــــــــــ

```
from django.shortcuts import  get_object_or_404 , redirect , render
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .cart import Cart
from shop.models import Product, ProductSizes
from .forms import CartAddProductForm

@require_POST
def cart_add(request , product_id , size):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    if size != 0:
        size_ = product.size.get(id=size)
    else:
        size_ = None

    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product , quantity=cd['quantity'] ,size_=size_, override_quantity=cd['override'] )
    return redirect("home")

@require_POST
def cart_remove(request , product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product=product)
    return redirect("cart.detail")


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={
            'quantity':item["quantity"],
            "override":True,
        })
    return render(request , "cart.html" , {"cart":cart})
```

---

```
#cart/forms.py & urls
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i , str(i)) for i in range(1,21)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,coerce=int)
    override = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False,widget=forms.HiddenInput)

---------------
urlpatterns = [
    path("" , views.cart_detail , name="cart.detail"),
    path("add/<int:product_id>/<int:size>/" , views.cart_add , name="cart.add"),
    path("remove/<int:product_id>/" , views.cart_remove , name="cart.remove"),

]
```

---

```
#html
<div class="shopping-cart-wrap">
    <a href="#"> <span class="cart-total-amunt">{{cart.get_total_price}} تومان</span><i class="icon-shopping-bag2 float-left"></i><span class="cart-total">{{cart|length}}</span></a>
    <ul class="mini-cart">
        {% for item in cart %}
            <li class="cart-item">
                <div class="cart-image">
                    <a href="{% url 'get.single.product' item.product.slug %}"><img alt="" src="/media/{{item.product.picture}}" width="80" height="80"></a>
                </div> 
                <div class="cart-title">
                    <a href="single-product.html">
                        <h4>{{item.product.name}}</h4>
                    </a>
                    <div class="quanti-price-wrap">
                        <span class="quantity">{{item.quantity}} ×</span>
                        <div class="price-box"><span class="new-price">{{item.price}} تومان</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="{% url 'cart.remove' item.product.id %}" href="#"><i class="icon-x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
  
        <li class="subtotal-box">
            <div class="subtotal-title">
                <h3>جمع کل :</h3><span>{{cart.get_total_price}} تومان</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mini-cart-btns">
            <div class="cart-btns">
                <a href="{% url 'cart.detail' %}">مشاهده سبد</a>
                <a href="{% url 'order.create' %}">پرداخت</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't we need an ID for each session cart entry to somehow separate items in cart ? I think the problem is with same product name so the products interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 2 days of struggling  finally  I found the solution

for adding products with different  sizes you have to pass the size model id to session instead of the product id

shop/models.py

```
class ProductSizes(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  price = models.IntegerField()
  off_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True , null=True)
  picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" )
  product = models.ForeignKey("Product" ,  on_delete=models.CASCADE )
  


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" )
    picture2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" , blank=True)
    picture3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" , blank=True)
    picture4 = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d" , blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category ,on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True ,null=True )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100 , db_index=True  , unique=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    is_amazing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amazing_till = models.CharField(max_length=10 , null=True , blank=True)
    off_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True , null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand ,on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True ,null=True )
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('get.single.product', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    class Meta:
        ordering=("name",) 
        index_together = (('id' , 'slug'),)
```

---

cart/cart.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product, ProductSizes



class Cart:
    def __init__(self,request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
            
        self.cart = cart
        
    # add to cart
    def add(self,product,size_,quantity=1,override_quantity=False):
        size_id = str(size_.id)
        if size_id not in self.cart:
            if size_.price:
                self.cart[size_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': size_.price}
            elif size_.off_price:
                self.cart[size_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': size_.off_price}

        self.cart[size_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()
  

        self.save()
    
    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True
    
    #remove from cart
    def remove(self,size_):
        product_id = str(size_.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()
    
    def __iter__(self):
        sizes_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = ProductSizes.objects.filter(id__in=sizes_ids)
        
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for size in products:
            cart[str(size.id)]['size'] = size
        
        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(item['price'] * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
        
    
    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

---

cart/views.py

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request , product_id , size):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    size_ = get_object_or_404(ProductSizes , id=size)

    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product , quantity=cd['quantity'] ,size_=size_, override_quantity=cd['override'] )
    return redirect("home")
```

---

The template

```
{% block cart %}
<div class="shopping-cart-wrap">
  <a href="#"> <span class="cart-total-amunt">{{cart.get_total_price}} تومان</span><i class="icon-shopping-bag2 float-left"></i><span class="cart-total">{{cart|length}}</span></a> 
    <ul class="mini-cart">
        {% for item in cart %}
            <li class="cart-item">
                <div class="cart-image">
                     <a href="{% url 'get.single.product' item.size.product.slug %}"><img alt="" src="/media/{{item.size.product.picture}}" width="80" height="80"></a>  

                </div> 
                <div class="cart-title">
                    <a href="single-product.html">
                        <h4>{{item.size.name}}</h4>
                    </a>
                    <div class="quanti-price-wrap">
                        <span class="quantity">{{item.quantity}} ×</span>
                        <div class="price-box"><span class="new-price">{{item.price}} تومان</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="{% url 'cart.remove' item.size.id %}" href="#"><i class="icon-x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
  
        <li class="subtotal-box">
            <div class="subtotal-title">
                <h3>جمع کل :</h3><span>{{cart.get_total_price}} تومان</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mini-cart-btns">
            <div class="cart-btns">
                <a href="{% url 'cart.detail' %}">مشاهده سبد</a>
                <a href="{% url 'order.create' %}">پرداخت</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock cart %}
```